# Create a link to send out that queries information into a certain place in my database

Tags: php, session

What is the best way to do this?  Am I able to start a session using information from the url, or can I use the link to make the information query into a certain primary key?

Would I use something like this:

```
if (!session_id()) {
    session_id($_GET[session_name()]);
   session_start();
}
```

In the url, I send I would have localhost/sites/pages/index.php?id=22342.

Comment: This is a coding issue unrelated to databases.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your database management system (MySQL, Oracle, RethinkDB, ...) supports a REST endpoint this will not be possible.

Usually the custodian of the data publishes a web API. The consumer GETs from the API and the API code performs the database look-up and formats the response.